# Ubuntu 16.04 going to emergency mode

Tags: 16.04, boot

[image: Messages while attempting to boot]

[image] 
<sup>`sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` info</sup>

I have tried options given below, but nothing worked.

```
After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" 
or ^D to try again to boot into default mode".
```

PS:

```
[UNSUPP] Starting of Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Autmount Point not supported.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions given after "Welcome to emergency mode"?

Comment: @Jos Yes. But nothing works.