# My system is not working after updating to kernel 4.15.0-23

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, updates, lubuntu

System: Lubuntu 18.04 x64

Yesterday I tried updating my system using "Software Updater" and after the update the system wouldn't boot up!

After update it asked my to restart, I restarted and it gave me some messages while booting up but I couldn't read them because they were gone quickly..

When the system was up it couldn't connect to any wifi network.

I tried restarting and it wouldn't boot up again.. It gives me this messages:

[image]

(Check the kernel error thing)

After that, this appears:

[image]
If I press enter, it gives me the root terminal.

And this is the apt log from /var/log/apt/history.log

```
Start-Date: 2018-06-12  00:08:08
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.376'
Install: intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20180425.1~ubuntu0.18.04.1, automatic), iucode-tool:amd64 (2.3.1-1, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-23:amd64 (4.15.0-23.25, automatic), amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20171205.1, automatic), linux-modules-4.15.0-23-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-23.25, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-23.25, automatic), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-23-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-23.25, automatic), linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-23.25, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.22.23, 4.15.0.23.25), gnupg-utils:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-22.24, 4.15.0-23.25), gpg-wks-client:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gnupg-l10n:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.22.23, 4.15.0.23.25), gpg-wks-server:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpg:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.22.23, 4.15.0.23.25), dirmngr:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpgv:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gnupg:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpg-agent:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.22.23, 4.15.0.23.25), gpgconf:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpgsm:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2018-06-12  00:09:44
```

My processor is Intel 4710hq and the update operating installed something related to AMD processors.. Maybe it broken something ?

So why my system isn't working? Is it a kernel problem? and how can I fix it?

Comment: An hour ago, someone asked a question where the same message `Failed to start Load Kernel Modules` suddenly popped up (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045813/ubuntu-16-04-going-to-emergency-mode). Coincidence?

Comment: Another [broken kernel](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17591/250300) version? :-( Anyway, APT should have kept the kernel version you were running before and you should be able to [boot it manually](https://askubuntu.com/q/82140/250300) as a temporary solution. Also, have you tried the suggested options (typing `exit` to the root prompt or pressing Control-D in the given prompt)?

Comment: @Melebius Using grub, I choose to boot up using 4.15.0.22.22 and it works just fine.

Comment: @ElderGeek and **Close Voters** the duplicate nominee doesn't answer how to fix broken kernel `4.15.0-23` like OP is asking. OP already knows *how to boot to an older kernel version* using grub.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've reviewed the question again, and I don't see where the OP is asking how to fix a broken kernel (which IMHO would be off-topic here and a better candidate for https://stackoverflow.com/ or better yet https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ) Considering the way the question is worded I would be more likely to think that the OP wants to be able to boot his system, in which case and the strategy of trying an older kernel version or perhaps a [newer one like 4.15.0.24.26](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/bionic/main/base/linux-generic)

Comment: Would seem sensible at least to me.

Comment: If you still have this problem, please [edit] your post to include the output of `systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I think your aystemd services comment us bang on. I saw a couple QA in AU on the related load modules problem.

Comment: Report a bug against the kernel

Answer (score 0):

For both Intel and AMD 64-bit processors Linux applications can contain `amd` in the filename.

For both Intel and AMD 32-bit processors Linux applications can contain `i386` in the filename.

It may or may not be a kernel problem. To find out you need to follow the instructions and type `journalctl -xb` and review the error messages.

Then post a more detailed description of the problem.